# android widget which launches activity on click

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, onclick

For me I have a button widget with a button that is just suppose to launch a helloworld activity when I click it. I've tried following many posts online including this one, and yet the problem still there. I press the button, nothing happens. I am working on version 2.3 of android. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

My widget:

```
public class IconWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            // first param is app package name, second is package.class of the main activity
            final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.followup","com.followup.FollowUpActivity");
            intent.setComponent(cn);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            final PendingIntent myPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.icon_widget_layout);


            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image_in_widget, myPI);

            final AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);             mgr.updateAppWidget(cn, views);
        }
    }

}
```

homescreeniconinfo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/icon_widget_layout"  >
</appwidget-provider>
```

icon_widget_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button android:name="@+id/image_in_widget"
        android:contentDescription="@string/iconDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

mainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.followup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
.
.
.
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    .
            .
            .
    <!-- Home icon widget -->
    <receiver android:name="IconWidgetProvider" 
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/homescreeniconinfo" />
    </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".FollowUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following logs when I add the widget:    09-20 22:05:46.062: W/AppWidgetService(110): updateAppWidgetProvider: provider doesn't exist: ComponentInfo{com.followup/com.followup.FollowUpActivity}
09-20 22:05:46.132: W/AudioFlinger(76): write blocked for 82 msecs, 153 delayed writes, thread 0xcb08
09-20 22:05:46.191: W/InputManagerService(110): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40826558

Comment: I've actually now cleared those errors by listening to the messages in my manifest, now, logcat is silent but FollowUpActivity is still not launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the event handler to your button?
Perhaps I'm confused here as it's been a while since I actually did some intense android programming, but from what I understand, this is what I've done to call an intent from another one in the past...

```
<Button android:name="@+id/image_in_widget"
        android:contentDescription="@string/iconDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickFunction"
        />
```

Paying extra attention to

```
android:onClick="onClickFunction"
```

Where "onClickFunction" would be a written method somewhere in your code that gets called when the button is clicked

```
public void onClickFunction(View view){ 
    //stuff to do on click
}
```

EDIT
This is ripped straight from the HelloWorld android tutorial which I have compiled and successfully run on my 2.3 Android Phone in the past
this is the xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

this is in the main .java file

```
/* called when the user clicks a button */
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.class is the class that is essentially a new application (from your case I believe you want it to be a Hello World app)

so you would make an XML for that called application and change/rewrite the DisplayMessageActivity class to do whatever "HelloWorld"-ey stuff you want...

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response, I really appreciate you helping me with this. I'm a touch confused though, what is the main .java file that you are referring to? the activity that I am launching, or the IconWidgetProvider?

Comment: Because i've tried adding the method to both, and I'm getting no love from the widget, rather, the best I see is 'problem loading widget' and logcat is saying '09-20 22:16:40.691: W/AppWidgetHostView(189): Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.followup/com.followup.IconWidgetProvider}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.Button'

Comment: The main java file would probably be the file that contains all the code you mentioned above. But I've never made an actual widget, this is just how it is done for actual apps. The ".java" file that contains 
'code' public class MainActivity extends Activity {
is the start of the main java file in my code...
I actually have the "sendMessage(View view)" in a different class within the same package and it still appears to work though...